# React.JS What is the best way to deal with an undefined prop

Tags: reactjs

I a currently learning React.JS. I am passing an array of objects to "AlbumContainer" but "this.props.albums[0].name_combined" is undefined. What is the best way to handle this. Thank you very much in advance.

```
class AlbumContainer extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const divStyle = {
            margin: '0px',
            border: '1px solid pink',
            color: 'blue',
            overflow: 'auto'
        };

        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    {this.props.albums[0].name_combined}
                </div>
                <div style={divStyle}>
                    SOME TEXT
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safest would be to do the following

```
{ this.props.albums && this.props.albums[0] && 
this.props.albums[0].name_combined ? this.props.albums[0].name_combined : '' }
```

Comment: You are a genius. I was getting an error becuase even the this.props.albums wasnt defined. I though i had tried everything. I especially thought i had the syntax wrong. Thank you so much

Comment: Just to add, you try looking at https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get to make it less verbose.